# Array items vuejs as one

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, vue.js

I have the following table

```
<table class="table-auto w-full">
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="items in planItems" :key="items.id">
      <td class="border px-4 py-2">{{ items }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm looping through all items, I have the following

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "PlanItem",
  props: {
    planIcon: {
      type: String,
      required: false
    },
    planIconAlt: {
      type: String,
      required: false
    },
    planName: String,
    planPrice: String,
    items: Array,
    planOrderLink: String
  },
  data() {
    return {
      planItems: this.items
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

and doing the following when I pass the component `items="[1GB]"`, however, my output is this

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is being treated as a string, and then is iterating over the characters of the string.  You have to use bind for it to execute it as Javascript, and your Javascript syntax is incorrect.

```
v-bind:items="['1GB']"
```

```
v-bind:items="['1GB','2GB','3GB']"
```

Comment: Hah ya, even the other guy answering this fell for the Javascript typo.  If this answered it for you, you can click the green arrow next to the answer to finalize and accept the answer.

Comment: Yeah had to wait for the timer to roll down, an easy and very rookie mistake to make haha

Answer (score 2):

try `:items="['1GB']"` instead

Explanation:
Your property is interpreted as a string, and not an array

Use `:` or `v-bind:` to use an array *(or anything that isn't a static string)* as a property